# Track sections of content on single page as virtual page view in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I'm trying to track when a "section" of a single page website is in the viewport and send that to Google Analytics as a virtual page view.

A few notes:

- I'm not a javascript coder (or any coder for that matter...)
- Already calling jquery 1.8
- Google analytics is working on the site and tracking menu clicks and time on page etc all very well.
- The sections are defined by div's with unique IDs e.g. #section-about
- I'm now trying to capture tracking info for people that *do not* use the menu
  but just scroll down the page and view each section
- I'd only want to capture a "page view" if the section was in view for longer than say
  2 seconds.

I found this which looks to get me part of the way there but I'm at a loss at so how to customise it:

```
$(function(){
    var tracking_active = '';
    var tracking = {
        'section-approach': '/testing/section-approach',
        'section-about': '/testing/section-about'
    };

    function scrollTrackPageview(){
        var section = '';
        $.each(tracking, function(key, value) {
            section = value;
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.'+key).offset())
                return false;
            return true;
        });

        if(!section || section == tracking_active)
            return false;

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', section]);
        //console.log('Bereich: '+section);

        tracking_active = section;
    }

    scrollTrackPageview();
    $(window).on("scroll", scrollTrackPageview);
});
```

Thanks in advance for the time and effort.

Comment: wouldnt it be easer just to check Google Analtyics to see how much time they have spent on the page?

Comment: It would for sure. Other alternative would be "scroll depth". But the client is pretty specific on this requirement to track the various sections of the page as virtual page views.

Comment: would be easer for you if he just let you do event tracking on the menu and track the rest of the page normaly.

Comment: The menu clicks are all being tracked no problem as that the easy one ;)

Comment: When you say "track the page normally", are you referring to time on page like suggested earlier? Unfortunately the client is very specific on this, they would like to track the sections as virtual page views as people scroll through the content.

Comment: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', section]);  <-- does all the normal logging of the Pageview. That's the magic command that does everything.    I'm not really sure i understand what your client thinks they will accomplish by logging it again as a virtual view besides a second hit.

Comment: It's a single page website, so there a few key and separate sections. Essentially they would be "normal pages" on a "normal site" and of course page tracking would work as expeceted then.

Comment: What they want to do is track what content is getting attention from site visitors on this single page, hence the need to track the various sections as detailed above.